# CLIPS Error: Illegal use of the module specifier when defrule

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips, expert-system

I want to define some module-rules to assert module-facts, and then batch get a group of facts list by `get-fact-list`, but an error occurred!

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (defmodule M)
CLIPS> (deftemplate M::T (slot k1))
CLIPS> (defrule M::T (testvalue 1) => (assert (M::T (k1 "v1"))))

[MODULDEF1] Illegal use of the module specifier.

ERROR:
(defrule M::T
   (testvalue 1)
   =>
   (assert (M::T
CLIPS>
```

expected:

```
CLIPS> (defmodule M)
CLIPS> (deftemplate M::T (slot k1))
CLIPS> (defrule M::T (testvalue 1) => (assert (M::T (k1 "v1"))))

CLIPS> (assert (testvalue 1))
CLIPS> (get-fact-list M)
;; return the facts that M::rulexx  assert
```

Why is the sytax error? How can I do it for the `defrule` of `module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use M::T in your assert command. Since the defrule is contained in module M, all deftemplates visible to M can be referenced without using a module specifier.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (defmodule M)
CLIPS> (deftemplate M::T (slot k1))
CLIPS> (defrule M::T (testvalue 1) => (assert (T (k1 "v1"))))
CLIPS> (assert (testvalue 1))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (get-fact-list M)
(<Fact-1>)
CLIPS>
```